# Swift pattern matching "if case" doesn't work for multiply cases at time

Tags: pattern-matching, swift2

Solution with **switch**:

```
switch number {
    case 1, 2, 3:
        ()
    default:
        ()
}
```

Now I try to do the same with `if case`:

```
if case number = 2, case number = 3 {
    () //doesnt work
}
```

I know that with numbers I can use range:

```
if case 1...3 = number {}
```

but it is not about that in this case.

Comment: Why do you want to use `if case` if it works with the shorter `switch`?

Answer (score 2):

If you write your switch statement with `case 1, 2, 5:` it gets internally rewritten to:

```
case 1: fallthrough
case 2: fallthrough
case 5: fallthrough
    // code...
```

which acts like an `OR` But in an `if case` all cases have to be met (similar to `&&`).

As workaround you could make an array and use the contains method:

```
if [2, 5, 7].contains(number) {
    // code
} else {
    // code
}
```

Or a more complex (but beautiful) way to deal with this problem would be to define a new operator like `|||` which chains multiple values together and `OR` them against one value:

```
infix operator ||| {
precedence 137 // higher than "==". lower than +,-
associativity left
}

func |||<T: Equatable>(left: T, right: T) -> T -> Bool {
    return { x in
        return x == left || x == right
    }
}

func |||<T: Equatable>(left: T -> Bool, right: T) -> T -> Bool {
    return { x in
        return left(x) || x == right
    }
}

func == <T>(left: T, right: T -> Bool) -> Bool {
    return right(left)
}

// now you can do this:
if numer == 2 ||| 5 ||| 7 {
    // code
} else {
    // code
}
```

Comment: Off-Topic: Indeed, `|||` is nice, but everyone's introducing new operators and it's a mess. Not against it, but everyone should watch [Clarity > Brevity](https://realm.io/news/swift-summit-swifty-methods-clarity-brevity/) talk by @radex. More these operators, more time needed to understand code by someone else (or even by author few months later). Use it, why not, but wisely :-)

Comment: You're right, new operators should be overthought very well. But this reads kind of too nice :)... "if number is (equal to) 2 or 5 or 7". Also consider the amount of code which you have to copy to your project in oder to get this behavior. If you do so make sure to document it...

Answer (score 1):

If you're not sure what it's doing, assembly is your friend. Your ...

```
if case number = 2, case number = 3 {}
```

... is translated to something like this ...

```
if number == 2 && number == 3 {}
```

... which is not what you want.

Isolate your problem to minimal example:

```
import Foundation
let number = 2
if case 2 = number, case 3 = number {
  print("yes")
}
```

Compile it and disassemble it.

[image]

And if you're not familiar with assembly, [Hopper](http://www.hopperapp.com) can help you with pseudocode generation (from disassembled binary). At least you should end up with an idea what it's really doing if you don't understand other things.

```
function _main_1001bfc70 {
    *(int32_t *)__TZvOSs7Process5_argcVSs5Int32 = rdi;
    var_0 = rsi;
    if (*_globalinit_33_1BDF70FFC18749BAB495A73B459ED2F0_token5 != 0xffffffff) {
            rax = _swift_once(_globalinit_33_1BDF70FFC18749BAB495A73B459ED2F0_token5, _globalinit_33_1BDF70FFC18749BAB495A73B459ED2F0_func5);
    }
    *__TZvOSs7Process11_unsafeArgvGVSs20UnsafeMutablePointerGS0_VSs4Int8__ = var_0;
    *__Tv11CommandLine6numberSi = 0x2;
    rdx = *__Tv11CommandLine6numberSi;
    var_40 = rdx;
    if (0x2 == rdx) {
            rdx = *__Tv11CommandLine6numberSi;
            var_32 = rdx;
            if (0x3 == rdx) {
                    rdx = 0x1;
                    rax = __TFSSCfMSSFT21_builtinStringLiteralBp8byteSizeBw7isASCIIBi1__SS("yes", 0x3, rdx);
                    var_8 = rax;
                    var_16 = rdx;
                    var_24 = rcx;
                    rax = __TFSs5printurFq_T_(&var_8, __TMdSS + 0x8);
            }
    }
    return 0x0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use one value per variable with one case in a `if case` condition.

You could append a `where` clause, but I suppose that would be even more verbose.

Comment: No, it is not true, because I can use `if case a=4, b=5`. Then I check if both `a` and `b` are under condition in same time.

Comment: OK, I will rephrase: "only one value per variable".

Comment: Technically you can use more than one, but it acts like &&. It has no sense, because it can't be 2 && 3.